# React native: Dynamic configs in app.json

Tags: react-native, expo

Is it possible to dynamically assign values to app.json file in react native?

i have this configs in my app.json file

```
{
  "expo": {
    "androidNavigationBar": {
      "barStyle": "light-content",
      "backgroundColor": "#000000"
    }
  }
}
```

to change the bottom soft keys background color in android devices

[image]

as I'm switching to different screens I would like **barStyle** and **backgroundColor** to be altered accordingly and be like

```
"barStyle": "dark-content",
"backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
```

Comment: Hello, did you found the solution?

Comment: Hi @OmarZaoujal! Unfortunately as of December 2023, there seems to be no solution to this. Maybe you should eject expo and see if there is a solution after that